# Monogoid hashes of hashes for embedded document

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

At the moment, when embedding document, I'm getting an array of hashes (here's my model:)

```
class Category

include Mongoid::Document

field :name,                        type: String
field :user_id,                     type: Integer
field :url,                         type: String
field :category_id,                 type: Integer
field :enabled,                     type: Boolean

belongs_to      :user
embeds_many     :subcategory,       store_as: 'subcategories'
...

end

class Subcategory

include Mongoid::Document
field :subcategory_name,            type: String
field :category_id,                 type: Integer
field :subcategory_id,              type: Integer
field :enabled,                     type: Boolean

embeds_many :product,               store_as: 'products'
embedded_in :category
...

end
```

Is there a way I could store it as hashes instead? Like:

```
{
...
"subcategory": {
    "subcat_1_id": {...},
    "subcat_2_id": {...},
    ...
},
...
},
```

without having to do data manipulation on the app (something like a Mongoid option that I'm not aware of?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is a single hash so I don't know what you're trying to do. `embeds_many` builds an array of hashes but you want a hash of hashes instead? What would the keys be? What would the values be?

Comment: I've edited my example to make it clearer (I wasn't referring to the main hash, but to the internal, category hash. Hopefully is clearer now). Currently category that has `embeds_many` subcategory I get an array (category) with hashes (subcategories). I want category to be a hash containing hashes (subcategories) where the id for each hash would be its id.

Comment: I don't think you can make `embeds_many` do that. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Basically this Rails app, needs to keep in sync with another app whiten in Node, so the data structure should be the same. I'll look at data manipulation then or change the structure in the other app (but I'm not sure if that'd be possible)> Thanks anyway.